# Do I need a British Transit Visa to go from Italy to Iceland?

Tags: uk, schengen, transit, transit-visas

I'm a Tunisian citizen with a valid Italian resident permit. I will be traveling from France to Iceland and I have to change both airline and airport in London, layover is 7 hours (between 7am to 3pm) in London. I'm curious if I need a transit Visa ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I have to change both airline and airport in London

Airport changes require you to go through immigration control. In fact, you will spend significant time travelling around London.

So yes, you will need a transit Visa.

Check your details at https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

I don't think the Italian Residence card makes much of a different here. You are a EU resident but not an EU citizen and you will still need to travel with your Tunisian passport.

FYI: this is not a great itinerary. Changing airports in London is inconvenient, time consuming and expensive.

Comment: An EEA/CH common format/credit-card sized residence permit allows visa-free landside transit in the UK on a reasonable itinerary (which EU-UK-Iceland is thanks to EasyJet et al.). But yes changing airports in London isn't an ideal experience.